# Can we make sure @beforesuite gets called before dataprovider?

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng-dataprovider, test-data

Can we follow the below method to initialise the test data? There are 2 points I want to implement.

1. Need to initialise/load the test data once from the file and use the same test data in all dataproviders.Thought to implement test data loader in @beforesuite class.
2. Need data from dataprovider and a parameter from testNG file at the same time in @test method.

   ```
   @BeforeSuite
   @Parameters(value = { "test_data_file" })
   public static synchronized void init(String test_data_file) {
       TestDataFactory.load(test_data_file);       
   }    
   @Test(dataProvider="dp_dummy",dataProviderClass = DP_1.class)
   public void testDummyAPI(TestData test_data,ITestContext context){
       String param = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("param");
   }        
   @DataProvider(name = "dp_dummy")
   public Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider(ITestContext context) {    
       List<TestData> test_data_collection = TestDataFactory.getTestData(targated_test_data);
       Object[][] test_data_set = new Object[test_data_collection.size()][1];    
       for(TestData test_data : test_data_collection)
           test_data_set[i++][0] = test_data;    
        return test_data_set;}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating your `test_data_set` correctly you can achieve your second point like this

```
 @Test(dataProvider="dp_dummy",dataProviderClass = DP_1.class)
    public void testDummyAPI( String p, Object[][] ob){
      System.out.println(p);      
      System.out.println(ob[0][0]);

    }   

    @DataProvider(name = "dp_dummy")
    public Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider(ITestContext context) {    
        List<TestData> test_data_collection = TestDataFactory.getTestData(targated_test_data);
        Object[][] test_data_set = new Object[test_data_collection.size()][1];    
        for(TestData test_data : test_data_collection)
            test_data_set[i++][0] = test_data;    
          String param = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("param");

           return new Object[][] {

               { param,  test_data_set}
           };
    }
```